# Как фильтровать данные, используя отношение многие-ко-многим в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Всем привет!
Бьюсь уже 2 дня, но никак не могу решить задачу.

Есть таблица товаров, категорий, цветов и т.д.
Также есть промежуточные таблицы для всех вышеперечисленных.

Для наглядности:

Таблица продуктов:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', 100);
            $table->integer('price')->index()->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Таблица категорий

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', 100);

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Таблица цветов

```
Schema::create('colors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', 100);

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Таблицы отношений:

```
Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('color_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->bigInteger('color_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('color_id')->references('id')->on('colors');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

В модели категории:

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
```

В модели продукта:

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class);
    }
```

**Никак не могу понять, как, к примеру найти товары, у которых следующий запрос:
Категория = кроссовки + Цвет = красный или зеленый**

Работает такой запрос:

```
$category = Category::where('title', 'кроссовки')
            ->first();
$products = $category->products;
```

Но это не верно. Так как нужно получить записи с остальными связями, то есть куда-то прописать

```
->with('categories',  'genders', 'brands', 'colors', 'materials')
```

ну и у меня запрос не только по категории, а еще и по цветам.
Еще работает такой запрос (с with), но тут я не могу понять, как добавить сортировку по категории и бренду:

```
        $products = Product::query()
            ->with('categories',  'genders', 'brands', 'colors', 'materials')
            ->get();
```

Любая помощь будет полезна)) Вроде задача то примитивная, но никак не могу справиться.

Comment: `Category::whereHas('categories', function($q) { $q->where('title', 'кроссовки'); })` но я бы лучше посоветовал юзать [Laravel-query-builder от spatie](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v5/features/filtering) (если это как-то связано с фильтрацией, а не просто хотелки)

Comment: @InDevX, Что-то не работает. Ошибка:
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Category::categories()
Если исправить Category на Product, то что-то получается, но товары не находит.

Comment: ну, первый параметр для whereHas это связь, метод для любой модели работает, да, там корректней Product:: whereHas, добавьте полностью составленный запрос